# Is there a way to automaticly get the label- and objectnames from an included svg file?

Tags: automation, svg, export

I'm pretty sure I read a solution for my problem a while back, but I can't find it anymore.
What I need is, that when I include an SVG image and make one (or more) build prozess, the names of all the labels and objects are exportet and attached to the texfile right under the picture.
The idea is that when i change an included svg file and build the pdf new, the finished pdf shows also the names of new labels and objects added in a table below(and the old,too, of course), without me needing to write all of them myself.
Any Help is very appreciated